# ffmpeg watermark

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using a static compiled lib of FFMPEG gotten from BAMBUSER for android.
The problem I am facing now is that FFMPEG version gotten from BAMBUSER does not support watermarking.

```
ffmpeg -sameq -i mirror_watermark.mp4 -vf "movie=mirror_watermark.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h [out]" output.mp4
No such filter: 'movie'

./configure --list-filters | grep movie
returns nothing
```

So I guess I have to use a newer version of FFMPEG but I do not know how to get started since with the BAMBUSER everything was already set I just added certain encoders and decoders to their script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this as a reference for compiling newer FFMPEG version which supports watermarking:
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **-overlay** for it. This Will Add Your Watermark on  a Particular position on the image or video as per dimensions.

Use below command:

```
-ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" test1.mp4
```