# Video Overlay from Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have been trying to add image overlay on video, so that overlay image gets displayed for particular timeframe only.

By following the instructions from following link I am able to do overlay video with image such overlaid image is displayed for entire video running length.
*http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1181*

**FFMPEG Command Used:**

```
/data/data/com.example.test/lib/libffmpeg.so -i /storage/sdcard0/e.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/a.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy /storage/sdcard0/testFFmpeg/cle3far.3gp
```

However I need to overlay image for particular time interval of video. So I tried following command but it didn’t work.

**FFMPEG Command that didn’t work:**

```
/data/data/com.example.test/lib/libffmpeg.so -i /storage/sdcard0/e.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/a.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=between(t\,0\,30) -codec:a copy /storage/sdcard0/testFFmpeg/cle3far.3gp
```

**Error Message:**

> Key ‘enable’ not found. ShelloutError initializing
>   filter 'overlay' with args '10:10:enable=between(t,0,30)' 
>   ShelloutError configuring filters.

By googling, I was able to find that I need FFMPEG 2.0, so I tried creating new ffmpeg library by following *http://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk*, but it didn’t work either.

It would be great if someone can get me anything from following:

1. an Android precompiled library for FFMPEG 2.0+ (libffmpeg.so)
2. or a way to do image overlay without FFMPEG

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818436/ffmpeg-watermark try this

Comment: ya i know this link already used but i m compiling this code after generting ffmpeg.so file -executing any ffmpeg command getting error Exit value 4.

Comment: Why are you using FFMPEG instead of the built in media player Android provides? (MediaPlayer and VideoView)

Comment: Actually i m creating video editing (Adding overlay) save video that's reason ffmpeg i m used..

Comment: have u got solution?

Comment: any idea how this can be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963522/android-stickers-on-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Will an overlay on top of your video player solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As of two years ago, it looks like this was not possible, so it may be that this hasn't changed.  You can find a specific referennce here: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-January/004062.html

I can't seem to find anything about it more recently.  There seems to be a way to start the overlay at a certain point in the video, but not to stop it later on (see this post for that information: [Overlay video after set time offset with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131020/overlay-video-after-set-time-offset-with-ffmpeg)).

The suggestion from the first link is to apply it to the segment of the video that you want to display the overlay on, so that may be the only way unfortunately as of now (at least using partially using FFMPEG).